# Hibernate/JPA mapping OneToOne relation / Heritage

Tags: jpa, inheritance

I'm building my entities, I want to know 2 things please :

1) I have for example a class named "Order" and a class named "Order_Details" , I want to make them OneToOne on both side , how can I make it?? (Same thing with Order and Order_Validation).

2) I created a class "User" and Inherited many classes ("Client"/"Manager"/"Accountant" ...) "Manager" is related to other classes ("Order" for example ) so my question is in the "Order" table should I put a relation with "User" or "Manager"?? (I don't have an ID in )

Thank you

Comment: Can you add more information to your second question. I hope Client, Manager, Accountant not seperate tables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm creating the entities and Hibernate will generate the talbles , What is the best solution to inheritate the classes with a (user_type) or make them in a seperate tables ? because each user type has a role ('Manager accepts orders" , "Accountant make order validation" etc...)

Comment: Zack P. Sorry for the delay. I would recommend going with USER table and USER_TYPE table. If a user will always belong to only on user type, then have a USER_TYPE_D key in USER table. If not have a one-to-many table like USER_TYPE_MAP table. Regarding the actions a user type can take, have a ROLES reference table and a separate table called USER_TYPE_ROLES which maps what role a user can play. So in JPA, you can User, UserType, Roles, UserTypeRoles etc and do a one-to-one or one-to-many mapping accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1) For your first question

```
Order Table

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "order")
private OrderDetail orderDetail;

Order_details Table. ( It will have a order_id column in it)

@OneToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID")
private Order order;
```

2) Depending on what you want to do.

I would recommend going with USER table and USER_TYPE table. If a user will always belong to only on user type, then have a USER_TYPE_D key in USER table. If not have a one-to-many table like USER_TYPE_MAP table. Regarding the actions a user type can take, have a ROLES reference table and a separate table called USER_TYPE_ROLES which maps what role a user can play. So in JPA, you can User, UserType, Roles, UserTypeRoles etc and do a one-to-one or one-to-many mapping accordingly.

Comment: 0
down vote
favorite
 

I have a problem , I have a OneToOne relation on both sides in "Commande" and "Demande" , the "Demande" object is created first so I made like this ;

Commande.java :

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_demandes")
private Demandes demande;

Demande.java :

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY , mappedBy="demande")
    private Commande commande;

But when I create a new "Commande" with an ID of existing "Demande", it creates a new "Demande" and stores it in the "Demande table".

How can I solve it ?

Thank

Comment: Commande c = new Commande(); Get Demande Object from DB as Demande d = demandeRepo.findOne(demandeId); then do c.setDemande(d) and d.setCommande(c);

Answer (score 0):

About #2...

It depends. Are you planning on having different tables for them? If this is the case, then you should put the relationship in Manager.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm creating the entities and Hibernate will generate the talbles , What is the best solution to inheritate the classes with a (user_type) or make them in a seperate tables ? because each user type has a role ('Manager accepts orders" , "Accountant make order validation" etc...)